# Transiting through Canada without going through border control

Tags: transit, canada, transit-visas, jamaican-citizens

I will be transiting through Canada on my way to Jamaica. My flight has a one-hour layover. I understand I will not exit the plane into at all during this time. The stop is to drop off and pick up passengers.

My question is, if I'm not exiting the plane or going through border control, do I still require a transit visa?

Comment: What is your citizenship?  Where are you coming from?  Which Canadian airport are you transiting through?

Comment: @michaelseifert my citizenship is Jamaican which I know I do need a transit visa if i'm going through border control, i'm traveling from the uk , through toronto pearson

Comment: I’m curious: what airline+flight would that be? A stop with passengers staying on board seems quite unlikely to me in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You require a Canadian [transit visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/transit/eligibility.html?lnktrk=visa_transit_air).

From the Canadian site above:

> **Who needs a transit visa?**
>
> You need a transit visa if you are from a visa-required country and:
>
> - your international flight stops at a Canadian airport on its way to another country
> - you will be connecting between two international flights at a Canadian airport
> - Some people can transit through Canada without a visa if they are travelling to or from the United States.

You can check [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?_ga=2.164918845.369506701.1519136789-1679451375.1519136789).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you will not legally be entering Canada.  You should really check with your airline on this, as this is an unusual arrangement.  If indeed you are just stopping in Canada and not disembarking, it is entirely possible that you will not need to clear Canadian customs and immigration.  There have been flights in the past, e.g. from Asia to the US via Vancouver, which functioned this way.  The plane stopped at Vancouver International Airport, dropped off the Vancouver-bound passengers (who did clear Canadian customs and immigration), and continued on to the US without taking on any new passengers.

What airline and flight are you taking, and what is the originating airport?

Comment: Airline probably wont let OP fly without a Canadian transit visa, nothing stopping them getting off the plane. Then the airline would be fined if OP tried to go through Canadian Immigration without a visa.

Comment: @SamJones The airline simply wouldn't let the passenger board without a Canadian visa or eTA, if it were required.  That's why I asked the poster to contact his airline, and asked what the airline and flight are.  On these flights through Vancouver, Canadian visas weren't required.  Passengers would only be admitted into Canada if that were the original plan or if there were an emergency.  (And emergency landings are already allowed and can be worked around.)